# redis-cli do a ttl command with a pattern

Tags: linux, shell, redis, redis-cli, nosql

I want to display the ttl of all the keys I have in Redis at once from the redis-cli shell.

I tried things like

```
redis-cli keys * | xargs redis-cli TTL
```

But it's not working, I keep getting the error:

```
(error) ERR wrong number of arguments for 'ttl' command
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using bash, be careful with globbing on "*". Also, xargs will need a replace-string like this:

```
redis-cli KEYS '*' | xargs -I{} redis-cli TTL {}
```

Comment: I just tried and I'm getting an error: `xargs: TTL: No such file or directory`

Comment: But I tried the command in my fish shell. Now that I tried in bash shell it works.